# Default spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.* properties to appy to multiple channels?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

With spring cloud stream, you can avoid redundant properties for each individual channel, by specifying "default" properties.

For example, if I have 2 channels bound to the same destination/exchange, I can do:

```
spring.cloud.stream.default.destination=myExchange

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myChannel1.group=queue1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.myChannel2.group=queue2
```

And queue1 and queue2 will both by bound to myExchange.

**That works as documented, and I do it for some properties.**

But....I'd like to do the same for **RabbitMQ** binding properties.

For example, if I want DLQ for all of my consumers/queues, do something like:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.dlq-ttl=10000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-exchange=
```

Otherwise, I have to specify those same 3 lines for every channel.

Is there any way to do this? I've tried several different permutations to no avail.

BTW, I'm on version 1.2.1.RELEASE of spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported. Please see https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#binding-properties section of the user guide

`To avoid repetition, Spring Cloud Stream supports setting values for all channels, in the format of spring.cloud.stream.default.<property>=<value>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but, obviously I know that it is possible for some properties. I even mention that in my question. But I can't get it to work for "rabbit" properties, like the ones that I mentioned. Can you provide an example of how to specify those specific DLQ/TTL types of properties across all channels?

Comment: My apology, I may have missed the gist of your question. It appears this may not be supported at the moment. Would you be kind enough to raise an issue here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: Not a problem. Will do. Thanks for responding!

Comment: For people brought here by Google, apparently the issue will be resolved in an upcoming release: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/pull/1477

Answer (score 0):

According to Spring Cloud Stream documentation, it is possible since version 2.1.0.RELEASE.

See [9.2 Binding Properties](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.1.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-stream.html#binding-properties).

> When it comes to avoiding repetitions for extended binding properties, 
>   this format should be used
>   `spring.cloud.stream.<binder-type>.default.<producer|consumer>.<property>=<value>`

Unfortunately so far I couldn't make it work. Did anyone get it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported yet.

See [3.2. RabbitMQ Consumer Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/docs/3.0.12.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html)

The following properties are available for Rabbit consumers only and must be prefixed with spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings..consumer..

including ttl/dlq*